# How can you retrieve the value of sys_guid() after an OracleCommand INSERT INTO

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, devart

I want to retrieve the value of a certain column that contain an Oracle db generated sys_guid() within a transaction.

```
public string GetGUID(OracleConnection connection) 
{ 
  string guid = "";
  connection.Open();
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
  OracleTransaction transaction;
  transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
  cmd.Transaction = transaction;
  cmd.Connection = connection;
  try
  {
   cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (NAME,DETAILS) VALUES (:nm, :dts)";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("nm", OracleDbType.VarChar);
   cmd.Parameters["nm"].Value = name;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("dts", OracleDbType.VarChar);
   cmd.Parameters["dts"].Value = details;
   cmd.Prepare();
   OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (reader.Read())
   {

   }
   reader.Close();
   transaction.Commit();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      transaction.Rollback();
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
      }
 return guid;
}
```

Table CUSTOMERS have a column ORDER that creates a guid with SYS_GUID(), how can I retrieve that guid?

Comment: `"INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (NAME,DETAILS) VALUES (:nm, :dts) RETURNING \"ORDER\" INTO :orderid "`

Comment: Side node: you have nothing to read, that's why `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Sorry misleading with :orderid, i corrected it. I dont insert any value to order column I leave Oracle database with sys_guid() to fill it.

Comment: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server-cs-conversion/insert-returning-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `returning .. into` [clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause) e.g.

```
   ...

   using (OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
     cmd.CommandText = 
       @"INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (
           NAME,
           DETAILS) 
         VALUES (
           :nm, 
           :dts)
         RETURNING 
           ""ORDER"" INTO :orderid";

     cmd.Parameters.Add("nm", OracleDbType.VarChar);
     cmd.Parameters["nm"].Value = name;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("dts", OracleDbType.VarChar);
     cmd.Parameters["dts"].Value = details;

     cmd.Parameters.Add("orderid", OracleDbType.VarChar);  
     cmd.Parameters["orderid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

     try {
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Just execute, nothing to read
       transaction.Commit(); 

       guid = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["orderid"].Value);
     }
     catch (Exception e) { //TODO: put more specific exception type
       transaction.Rollback();   
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);     
     } 

     return guid;
   }  

   ...
```

Comment: Worked excellent i used query "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (NAME, DETAILS) VALUES (:nm, :dts)  RETURNING ORDER INTO :orderid" without the @ prefix. Thanks a lot!